# TREEview out of database

Tags: c#, mysql, treeview

I got a treeview called tableVw.

Into TableVw the tables are showd out of the database.

[image]

i want to show table in parent and title as childeren. when you click on the childeren you get the info in a panel with textboxes where you can edit them. AND i dont know how many table or titles there are.

With follow code i only get the tables:

```
MySqlConnection sconn = new MySqlConnection("User ID=root;Password=;Initial Catalog=cmstt;Data Source=localhost");
            MySqlCommand cmd = sconn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SHOW TABLES;";
            MySqlDataReader Reader;
            sconn.Open();
            Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                string row = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    row += Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ", ";
                tableVw.Nodes.Add(row);
            }
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Did it fail? if so how?  Be more specific and don't just ask us to write your code for you.  BTW try looking up databinding what you are doing there is bizare. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: got a database with tables:
-content
-promo
-users
These should be parents in listview.
Under 'content' i got followed.
title = Page1 text = This is Page1.
.....
The title of these should be shown as a child.

When you click on the child it shows in a panel (textboxes) the text and title(editable).

Comment: have you heard of self joins ? or joins in general ?